# How can I implement background services in flutter For fetching data from server?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to create an app which runs always in background and fetch data from server in every 15 min. How can i implement this background service in my app?

Comment: Short answer; you  should not do this. Polling is not efficient for battery or network. You can use periodic background refresh on iOS but you cannot schedule it for a specific interval. It typically runs a few times per day. Either fetch the data when the user is actually running your app or use push notifications of they need to know about changes when they are not running the app

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib : https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch which provide a full example

Comment: Should this package able to run in whole day?

Comment: I don't know, you shoul try it

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run a function for every 15mins you can use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager . You can wrap your function inside the work manager to execute in the background. Something like this..

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
```

Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async { **your function/task here***})}

You can also try alarm manager plugin here https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager if you are considering time as main constrain.

Comment: this is android only plugin. i want to run in both android and iOS.

Comment: workmanager is discontinued, last update was July 2020.